# How to determine if a (cost) function is convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am playing around with some machine learning models and want to try out different cost functions to see how the models react. One of the requirements for a cost function that can guarantee us to find a global minimum (using gradient descent) is that the cost function must be convex.

How do I determine whether a function I'm using is convex (in the realm of machine learning) and only has a global minimum?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I don't have a full understanding of the topic yet...

Comment: Take the second derivative, if it is positive the function is convex. For example, $x^2$ or $\cosh x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Check whether it is convex from the definition.
- Check that that Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite.
- Also, multiplying a convex function by a positive constant, give you a convex function. Adding two convex functions give you a convex functions too. This is useful to see that some regularized objective functions are convex.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "Check whether it is convex from the definition."?

Comment: pick two elements from the domain, $x, y$, and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, verify that $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y ) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$. It might not be easy to verify that directly.

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible to prove these points? thank you!

Comment: I think those results are standard textbooks result